GuestPaymentInformationManagementPlugin must be of type Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface when placing order
Magento 2.4.6-p3
I am getting this error when placing an order in my Magento 2 checkout:

TypeError:
Magento\Persistent\Model\Checkout\GuestPaymentInformationManagementPlugin::beforeSavePaymentInformation():
Argument #4 ($paymentMethod) must be of type
Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentInterface,
Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Interceptor given

I recompiled, deployed and cleared the cache, issue remains. Also tried using different payment methods, all return the same error.
I am using Luma checkout ... any idea what might be wrong?
Full error log: https://pastebin.com/VvkgC4UV

Can you add full error trace for logs or provide the log file.

Sure, I added the link in my post above ...

beforeSavePaymentInformation can you check in your code if this function has been override in app/code

After reviewing your logs, it seems that "Magestore/WebposIntegration/Plugin" is conflicting with the code. Could you try disabling this extension and let me know if it resolves the issue?
